# Decoration elements and Accessibility

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I'm not sure how to deal with anything(except images) that is used for design/decoration only in terms of accessibility. For example, if in case like this I'll use an image, I'd simply use `alt=""` or use CSS background image, so the AT for example will ignore it. But what if I'm using some `<div>` or anything else? It can be a div with some CSS styling that is presented in a code-way, instead of image, or it can be some text with CSS styling so it will be just for decoration(instead of images), or really, anything else. How should I mark it so it will be ignored in a proper way by AT?

Simple example(for request):

```
<div><span>For Decoration</span></div>

div{
  width:0; height:0;
  border-bottom:116px solid #009;
  border-left:500px solid #900;
  margin:0 auto;
}
div span{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  margin:0 auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:150px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a functional example? I ask because depending on the elements, how it appears in the page, whether it has any other possible function, whether it interacts, with script, etc, there may be more than one answer. If you do not have a specific example and this is a general question, that would be good to know as well.

Comment: Yes, this is theoretical, a general question

Comment: You have asked a couple questions in a short time about accessibility. I do not know your skill level, but perhaps this free training course can help? https://www.udacity.com/course/web-accessibility--ud891

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this:

1) if you are using an empty tag such as a div with no text in it, the screen reader will ignore it automatically. You don't need to do anything in particular.

2) if you are using a tag with text inside you should: a) give it an aria-hidden="true" if you don't want the screen-reader to read the text or b) give it a role="presentation" if you do want the screen-reader to read the text but not announce it as a particular type of element.

### -------------------

*Based on the comments on this post I have added code below showing an example.  It shows when you wouldn't need to do anything (the first and last div) and when you would want to use aria-hidden and role="presentation".*

*The top line is purely for decoration.  Part of it is empty divs and part of it is text.  The different words for "Hello" in the p tag should be seen but don't need to be read since they're purely ornamental which is why I am using role and aria-hidden on it.*

```css
.end {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
.end-left {
  border-left-color: #999;
  border-top-color: #999;
}
.end-right {
  border-right-color: #999;
  border-top-color: #999;
}
.languages {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'copperplate', 'century gothic';
  color: #999;
}
.languages span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="end end-left"></div>
<p class="languages" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
  <span class="english">Hello</span>
  <span class="french">Bonjour</span>
  <span class="italian">Ciao</span>
  <span class="spanish">Hola</span>
  <span class="hinid">Namaste</span>
  <span class="persian">Salaam</span>
</p>
<div class="end end-right"></div>
<h1>Languages</h1>
<p>Welcome to your first language lesson. You will learn how to speak fluently.</p>
```

Comment: But the `role=presentation` isn't for this, as far as I got it. Because if you look for example here: `<h1 role="presentation">Inner text has no meaning here</h1>` the only thing that will be ignored here is that this text isn't a heading, but the text it self will be presented to the user with AT. So is it really wise to use `aria-hidden=true` in all other cases except images(with `alt=""`), perhaps there's some other, more elegant way?

Comment: Also, if I'll use `aria-hidde=ture` this will mean it's not visible to ANY user. Not only with AT. `Indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible or perceivable to any user as implemented by the author` from here:https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden

Comment: Aria-hidden doesn't make content hidden to the eye. It simply implies content is hidden to the eye. You still need to style the content to be visually hidden with CSS.  Remember, aria only changes the screen-reader understanding, it doesn't change the visual or actionable reality.

Comment: And, correct, presentation takes meaning away from the element but reads the text itself which is what I said in 2b.

Comment: I wouldn't bother using either aria-hidden or role=presentation with an image. A null alt would suffice.

Comment: So, it sounds like my 1st suggestion is the way you want to go.  If you have a div that contains no text and is simply there to create a decorative element with CSS you need not do anything else. It will be ignored by the screen reader. Does that fit your scenario?

Comment: I added an example to this post showing when you wouldn't need to do anything (the first and last div) and when you would want to use aria-hidden and role="presentation" (the p tag with all the versions of the word hello).